# Why doesn't Javascript execute the code in sequence?

Tags: javascript

I have this simple function

```
function getArticles(page){
  page = page || 1;
  loading = false;
  var articlesCache = getArticlesCache(page);
  if(articlesCache){
    articles = articlesCache.data;
  }else{
    make a request and then save the cache;
  }
  loading = false;
  pageAttr = {
    currentPage : articlesCache.current_page
    lastPage : articlesCache;last_page
  }
}
```

If I do this, `loading` initializes as `false` and `pageAttr` tries to create the property with `articlesCache`, which doesn't exist yet.

Here is the thing, `loading`  and `pageAttr` run before the if/else. I know I can put this code inside the if/else , but I do not think it is good, because I'm going to make twice which I can do once. So, how do I make the code run in sequence like in PHP and others programming languanges?

Comment: what is getArticlesCache? is that an Async function?  You also have many syntax errors in your code. what is `make a request and then save the cache`?

Comment: is `getArticlesCache` returning a promise? in that case, you'll need to use `.then()` or `.success()` functions instead of the if/else

Comment: *"loading and pageAttr run before the if and else statments"* - That can't happen. Javascript doesn't execute statements out of sequence like that.  What *can* happen is that getArticlesCache() might not work the way you expect such that the articlesCache variable doesn't get set to the value you expect - if you show the code for getArticlesCache() we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the getArticlesCache function, you could modify it to fire a callback when finished.

```
function getArticlesCache(page, callbackFunction){
  //your existing code.
  callbackFunction();
}

var articlesCache = getArticlesCache(page, function() { 
  //code to execute when getArticlesCache is Finished...
  alert( 'getArticlesCache is Finished!' ); 
});
```

Read more: http://mrbool.com/callback-functions-in-javascript/28614#ixzz46PNJgXyH

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is fire the n-steps functions asynchronously.
I suggest you to read this posts:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise